# Wordpress post type archive not working even permalinks is flushed

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't know why my custom post type archive link returns 404 error page, below is an array where i build my CPT :

```
Array ( 
    [label] => Agendas 
    [labels] => Array ( 
        [name] => Agendas 
        [singular_name] => Agenda 
        [add_new] => Add New 
        [add_new_item] => Add New Agenda 
        [edit_item] => Edit Agenda 
        [new_item] => New Agenda 
        [all_items] => All Agendas 
        [view_item] => View Agenda 
        [search_items] => Search Agendas 
        [not_found] => No agendas found 
        [not_found_in_trash] => No agendas found in Trash 
        [parent_item_colon] => [menu_name] => Agendas 
    ) 
    [public] => 1 
    [show_ui] => 1 
    [supports] => Array ( 
        [0] => title 
        [1] => editor 
) 
    [show_in_nav_menus] => 1 
    [show_in_rest] => 1 
    [_builtin] => 
    [hierarchical] => 1 
    [rewrite] => Array ( [slug] => agenda [with_front] => ) 
)
```

Post type is woking fine from admin, but from front i get 404 error, i already flush permalinks without success.

## UPDATE

I solved it by adding 'has_archive' => true,

Thanks

Comment: How are you accessing the custom post? what is the url? don't forget that posts use the single.php template as a fallback for all posts, if you want to create a template only for that custom post type you need to create a file named single-CPT_SLUG_HERE.php

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, i resolved it by addin 'has_archive'  => true